# load file as part of a js script

Tags: jquery

I have this script in the head of my page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery.PictureSlides.set({

            /* some settings here */

                images : [
        <?php include"01.inc.txt"; ?>
            /* myfile is an array, loaded as default file when user first reads the page, and looks like :
                {
                image : "001.jpg", 
                alt : "Name #1",
                text : "Title #1",
                desc : "Desc #1"
                },
                {
                image : "002.jpg", 
                alt : "Name #2",
                text : "Title #2",
                desc : "Desc #2"
                },
           and so on... */
        ]
            /* some other settings here */
</script>
```

Then, in the body, I have my menu :

```
   <ul id="main-nav">
    <li>
     <a class="main-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li>
     <a class="main-link" href="#">Main Link</a>
      <ul class="sub-links">
        <li><a href="01" id="link-1" class="menuloader" title="">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="02" id="link-2" class="menuloader" title="">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="03" id="link-3" class="menuloader" title="">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="04" id="link-4" class="menuloader" title="">link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

My questions are :

- Is it possible to have a click on any link of the menu, and then the corresponding file ("01.inc.txt" or "02.inc.txt"...) loaded/read by the script, without refreshing the page ?
- If "yes", what would be the best way, what can I sart with, or what shall I start looking for in the doc ?

EDIT II : so, according to your answers, this would be a good start ?

```
$(document).on('click', '.menuloader', function(){

var thisId = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "addfile.php", /* here, I open my file (identified as "thisID") with PHP, parse it, read lines, then send them back ? */
    data: "file_id="+thisId
    }).done(function(data) { /* get results here ? like => images : [ {data ?} ] */ });
});
```

Comment: No, you can't execute php on the client. You can however use ajax to get that data.

Comment: Yes that should work. However you need `.done` function to receive data from server and data should be inside `{}` like `data: {file_id: thisId}`

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for is AJAX. Jquery has few functions that are great for using ajax([jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) , [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) , [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)). Read up the docs on them.

Ajax is basically a technology that lets you send a request in the background to the server and retrieve the answer. It can be a text file, a php script etc. The AJAX call can be bound to the event and run for example on button click. PHP Script would than send necessary information back to the page which you can directly use in you JS code.

A sample code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "memory.php"
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        $("div#memoryUsage").html(msg);
    });//ajax
```